# Почему не получается получить и отобразить страницу с помощью file_get_contents?

Tags: php, file-get-contents

```
<?php
$homepage = file_get_contents('http://www.pornhub.com/');
echo $homepage;
?>
```

Получаю ошибку

> Warning: failed loading cafile stream:
>   `C:\xampp\apache\bin\curl-ca-bundle.crt' in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\addfriend\index.php on line 2
>
> Warning: file_get_contents(): Failed to enable crypto in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\addfriend\index.php on line 2
>
> Warning: file_get_contents(http://www.pornhub.com/): failed to open
>   stream: operation failed in C:\xampp\htdocs\addfriend\index.php on
>   line 2

Comment: Pornhub использует `https` протокол)

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте так

```
<?php
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 
 'https://pornhub.com');
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION,3); 
   $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    echo $result;
```

Под виндой есть проблема с доступом к сертификатам. Поэтому нужно добавить сертификат непосредственно к curl. Скачать корневой  сертификат можно по ссылке

http://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html

И добавляем опции

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, **DIR** . 
     "/certs/cacert.pem");
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 
     true);

Comment: Извините, я не очень понял вас. Я новичок и в этом не разбираюсь.
Так как вы написали я пробовал - не сработало. Что делать с файлом cacert.pem? Можно чуть подробнее написать пожалуйста?

Comment: Куда добавлять опции?